# Using \footnotemark with letters

Tags: numbering, footnotes

There are many answers to questions about `\footnotemark`, but I couldn't find one to mine. I have the following code and it works fine. What I need to use is `\footnotemark [a]` instead of `\footnotemark [1]`, but I always get an error. Is it a `\usepackage` problem?

```
\begin{table}[thb!]
\centering
\caption[Sample table]{Params}
\label{tab:params}
\vspace{0.5 cm}
\begin{tabular}[width=0.5\columnwidth]{|c|c|c|}\hline
\textbf{Params}& \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Values }\\\hline
\textbf{$x$} & high  & $2$ $\left[\frac{mol}{h}\right]$\footnotemark [1]\\\hline
\textbf{$y$} & low & $0.2$ $\left[\frac{mol}{h}\right]$\footnotemark [2]\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\footnotetext [1]{parameter value are taken from \cite{bla}.}
\footnotetext [2]{parameter value are taken from \cite{blabla}}
```

Comment: [welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your table may be typeset quite easily with the help of a `threeparttable` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
   \begin{threeparttable}
   \caption[Sample table]{Params}
   \label{tab:params}
   \vspace{0.5 cm}
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
      \textbf{Params}& \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Values }\\\hline
      $\mathbf{x}$ & high  & $2$ $\left[\frac{mol}{h}\right]$\tnote{\emph{a}}\\\hline
      $\mathbf{y}$ & low & $0.2$ $\left[\frac{mol}{h}\right]$\tnote{\emph{b}}\\\hline
   \end{tabular}
   \begin{tablenotes}
      \footnotesize
      \item[\emph{a}]{parameter values are taken from \cite{bla}.}
      \item[\emph{b}]{parameter values are taken from \cite{blabla}}
   \end{tablenotes}
   \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

As the image demonstrates, the footnotes will be set directly below the table. I can't tell from your posting if this is something you want (or possibly don't want). In my experience, if a page has both a table and running text and both contain footnotes, it's almost invariably a good idea to place the table-related footnotes immediately below the table -- as long as the table isn't set at the very bottom of the page, I suppose...

Note that the widths of the first and third parts (caption and footnotes) of the three-part table are automatically set to the width of the second part -- the `tabular` (or `tabular*`, `tabularx`, etc.) environment.

Answer (score 14):

The argument of `\footnotemark` is the *value* of the footnote counter. The appearance of the footnote counter is controlled by the macro `\thefootnote`. This can be changed to generate small letters instead of the footnote symbols:

```
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
```

This can be done globally in the preamble, if all footnotes should be numbered by letters or locally:

```
\begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
  \begin{table}
    ...
    \footnotemark[1]
    ...
    \footnotemark[2]
    ...
  \end{table}
  \footnotetext[1]{...}
  \footnotetext[2]{...}
\endgroup
```